# Text kerning in Microsoft rich text box

Tags: visual-studio, richtextbox, rtf, text-processing

This one has me awfully confused...

I am trying to display kerned RTF text in a Visual Studio Visual Basic `RichTextBox` control (having so far tried under VS2010 and VS2012). Simply, I create a Windows Form project, add two `RichTextBox`'s (`RichTextBox1` and `RichTextBox2`) to the form, no change to default properties, and include the following VB code:

```
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Initialise(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim txtRTF As String = "{\rtf1\ansi" & _
                               "{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}" & _
                               "\f0\pard" & _
                               "\expndtw-60 a" & _
                               "\expndtw200 b" & _
                               "\expndtw-20 c}"

            RichTextBox1.Rtf = txtRTF
            RichTextBox2.Paste() ' RichTextBox2 formats properly iff clipboard holds ANY valid rtf content
            RichTextBox2.Rtf = txtRTF

        End Sub

    End Class
```

The `txtRTF` `String` contains, as best as I can tell, minimal valid `RTF` markup and text.

Here's the confusing bit: text displayed in `RichTextBox1` is not kerned, despite `\expndtw` (expand twips) RTF markup, *BUT* text displayed in `RichTextBox2` *is* properly kerned, *if and only if* the clipboard holds ANY valid RTF content (e.g., any text has first been copied into the clipboard from an MS Word document). Text displayed in `RichTextBox2` is *not* properly kerned if clipboard contents is not RTF format.

Result of running if the clipboard does not contain RTF-formatted data (or if the `RichTextBox2.Paste()` code is removed or commented out):

[image: Improper <code>RichTextBox</code> kerning]

Result of running if the clipboard holds any random RTF-formatted text:

[image: Proper <code>RichTextBox</code> kerning]

Questions:

1. *Why* on earth should it matter that I have previously pasted RTF-format (and *not* non-RTF format) into the `RichTextBox2` control before setting the `RichTextBox2.Rtf` field?
2. More importantly, how can I (in VB) programmatically display properly kerned text in a `RichTextBox` control without the absurdity of first pasting random `RTF` format text into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that took a lot of work!  Nevertheless, problem now solved.

It turns out that, although the RTF spec notes that `\ltrch` (left-to-right character run) is the default state, it seems that `RichTextBox` objects don't necessarily agree.  Including a `\ltrch` (or even, oddly, a `\rtlch`) control sequence in the RTF markup stream completely solves the failure-to-kern problem.  RTF text kerning via `\expndtwN` and `\expndN` now works perfectly well.  No need for silly `Paste()` commands to pre-configure the `RichTextBox` control into its proper state!